# Using pyinstaller to try and make a standalone exe to produce a tkinter window, but the generated exe isn't making any window; what am I missing?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Good evening, noble experts.  I'm likely going to betray some of my ignorance again!

I've written a python script that creates a window in tkinter, and works the way I'd like it to so far as I can tell.  What I'd like to do now is turn it into a standalone .exe that will, upon being double-clicked, generate said window for use.

I've installed pyinstaller, and put in the fateful commands to create the .exe from my humble .py

```
.../python pyinstaller.py -w -F examplename.py
```

and shiny new .exe was made and put into the /dist folder.  The problem I seem to be encountering, is that running this application doesn't open up the tkinter window in the script, and I'm not sure why.  Based on the tutorials I've seen online and my own limited understanding of the process, I suspect that it may have something to do with a SPEC file, which I have not yet fiddled with as I'm not 100% certain that is what's causing this issue.

I would greatly appreciate any insight into this, and if I've neglected key information that you need, I will try and fill that in asap.  Thank you!

Edit: so it turns out that one of the modules that I was using in this, (scipy), has some known issues with pyinstaller.  When I commented out the scipy stuff, it worked the way it was supposed to... minus the scipy of course.  I'm going to have to spend some time figuring out/understanding the workaround for it.

Comment: Can you remove `-w` and see what the console outputs?

Comment: I'm down, quick question though; how do I make it so that the console output doesn't automatically close itself?  ...or would that autoclosing indicate another problem altogether?

Comment: If you're running Windows 7/8, shift + right-click the folder where the binary is at (like the icon, not the inside of the folder) and open a Command Prompt window in there. Then, you can just run `name_of_binary.exe` and it'll just print to the console.

Comment: Ah, thank you.  The last line says "ImportError: connot import name shortest_path" and the line above looks like it's telling me that it has some difficulty importing something from the scipy module.  Would it maybe be worth a shot to try reinstalling scipy?

Comment: Probably not. What does that `import` line look like?

Comment: Update: I commented out the sections of the code that use scipy, and it now opens the window that I wanted!  Now it just remains to get scipy working properly on this computer, so it's a partial solution at least.  The import line is: 'File "c:\Python27\examplename\build\pyi.win32\examplename\out00-PYZ.pyz\scipy.sparse.csgraph", line 148, in <module>'

Comment: This might be useful: http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/83

Comment: That does look relevant.  Thanks for the link, I'm going to see if I can use that workaround for what I'm doing here.

Comment: Whilst it appears you had a different issues, I had the same result (ie, no result) when I was building the file `app.py`which imported a module also named `app`. I had to rename `app.py` to something different than the name of the imported module (eg, `run_app.py`).